# Install service from my console app not using installutil

Tags: c#, service, installation

I have a solution I have split in 3 parts.

1. a console app
2. a dll
3. a service

All the main code for my application is in the dll and the console app just calls a single method in the dll that then runs my application.

I designed it in this way hoping to make it easy for myself to test the code not having to install the service over and over again. So my plan is that the main method in the service which is called by the timer should call the same method in the dll.

I am missing 2 parts of code. 1 for installing the service and 1 for uninstalling the service. I would like to be able to do both from the console app via arguments.

Searching for code examples for installling service I can only examples that use the installutil application which is not what I want.

Comment: what is the point of installing and uninstalling a service from your console on demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the link provided here:

https://ramveersingh.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/install-window-service-programmatically/